# How to play .MOV files in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-camera, xamarin.essentials

We are migrating a Xamarin.iOS posting feature (Instagram like) that was done using a custom camera view to Xamarin Essentials Media Picker.

When trying to play a video file from the camera roll using PickVideoAsync I get a .MOV file and when selecting the **same video**, but using the previous version it is a .mp4 file!

previous version file path:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/657B8450-EDD5-4704-98BF-34B3406A8A37/Documents/IM-20201031151047346.mp4
```

new version file path:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C8821691-6B3E-4F25-9E95-7299CD78676A/Library/Caches/trim.DBCDDE49-0D23-4C15-A450-E38E51421DD7.MOV
```

The only explanation I can think of is that the video exists in two different formats in the device?

Now the second part of the problem:

I was hoping I could use the same implementation for the Post editing screen, where the user adds comments, location, etc...

This is implemented using AVPlayer, but it does not support .MOV videos.

Is there a way to:

A) An alternative to AVPlayer that supports .MOV? (preferred solution)

B) Enforce Xamarin Essentials to get the mp4 file?

C) Convert MOV to mp4 inside the app? (I guess this will probably be slow, if it is possible)

This is the AVPlayer implementation:

```
var videoUrl = GetVideoUrl(mediaViewModel.MediaUrl);
var playerItem = AVPlayerItem.FromUrl(videoUrl);
var player = AVPlayer.FromPlayerItem(playerItem);
var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer.FromPlayer(player);
player.Seek(CMTime.Zero);
playerLayer.Frame = View.Bounds;
View.Layer.AddSublayer(playerLayer);
```

Comment: `mov` is just a container and depending upon what is in that container AVPlayer can/won't play it. What a/v codecs are within that mov that you are trying to play? Also iOS would not maintain two copies of the same video file in different containers.

Comment: How do I find out what a/v codecs are within that MOV file? Weirdly, when I open the video using Xamarin Essentials Media picker I get a .MOV file and  the old implementation gets a mp4 file for the same video. @SushiHangover

Comment: @joseluisgonzalezclua Hi, if not minding using `MPMoviePlayerController`, it can play `.mov` file.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT FYI: `MPMoviePlayerController`/`MPMoviePlayerViewController` has been deprecated in iOS-9,  `AVPictureInPictureController`/`AVPlayerViewController` are their replacements. But, again, it depends upon what is in the `mov` container, example: a video stream encoded in the ProRes codec and packaged in a `mov` will not play.

Comment: @SushiHangover Okey, that's cool. Then we can use `AVPlayerViewController` to play mov file, but depends on file's container.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the GetVideoUrl was not right.

By changing it to NSUrl.CreateFileUrl(videoUrl, null); it worked. Even with a mov file!

Thanks for the support.